# Github pages syntax highlighting - very poor contrast

Tags: github, github-pages, syntax-highlighting

I am using Github Pages with Jekyll forked from JekyllNow.

This is what I have

````
Python

```python
for i in Q:
    print(i)
    while True:
            print(i)
```
````

In Github preview, the contrast is great with the syntax highlighting very clear.

[image]

When the page is actually deployed, the contrast is poor probably because of the colours used in conjunction with the background colour.

[image]

Is there a way to improve this? Have better syntax highlighting on Github pages?

My _config.yml contains the defaults.

```
# Jekyll 3 now only supports Kramdown for Markdown
kramdown:
  # Use GitHub flavored markdown, including triple backtick fenced code blocks
  input: GFM
  # Jekyll 3 and GitHub Pages now only support rouge for syntax highlighting
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    # Use existing pygments syntax highlighting css
    css_class: 'highlight'
```

Is there anything I can change here which will give me syntax highlighting with a better contrast like the one I see in preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and create a new CSS file, say `syntax-highlighting.css`, in your site's assets folder. Paste the GitHub Rouge theme CSS you got from [`mzlogin/rouge-themes`](https://github.com/mzlogin/rouge-themes), see [`mazhuang.org/rouge-themes/`](https://mazhuang.org/rouge-themes/).
Include this CSS file in your site's main layout to make sure it is loaded on every page. You can do this by adding a line like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/syntax-highlighting.css">
```

Sometimes, other styles in your site's CSS can conflict with the Rouge styles, leading to unexpected appearances. In such cases, inspect the problematic elements using your browser's developer tools and override any styles as necessary.

For instance, if the background color of your code block is causing the poor contrast, you can add a style to explicitly set the background color:

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: #f6f8fa; /* GitHub-like background color */
}
```

Once you have made the above changes, you need to rebuild and redeploy your site for the changes to take effect.

---

> For python, practically every word in the code seems to be highlighted by the entry `.highlight .nx { color: #555 } /* Name.Other` in the `highlights.scss` file. I am wondering if this is a bug!

If the `.highlight .nx { color: #555 }` rule is being applied excessively to your Python code, then it is likely that the `Name.Other` token (represented by `.nx` in the CSS) is being overused by the highlighter for Python. That could indeed be a quirk or a bug in the version of Rouge you are using.

[Rouge uses lexers for different languages](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge/wiki/List-of-supported-languages-and-lexers), and it is possible that the lexer for Python in the version of Rouge that Jekyll uses on GitHub Pages is not as refined as some others, such as the one for Ruby. That might explain why marking the Python code as Ruby results in seemingly better highlighting.

As a quick fix, you can try and alter the `.nx` color to something less distracting:

```scss
.highlight .nx {
    color: #333; /* or any other color that provides better contrast */
}
```

That is not ideal since it might make actual `Name.Other` tokens less visible, but it will make the code look better for the time being.

Also, make sure your `Gemfile` reflects the latest version for [rouge (4.1.x)](https://rubygems.org/gems/rouge/versions/4.1.3), to check if the issue still persists then.

```rb
gem 'rouge', '~> latest_version'
```

```bash
bundle update rouge
```

---

> I use [Jekyllnow](https://www.jekyllnow.com/) - i.e. I don't install ruby or build locally. I am not sure where or how I check the Gemfile - don't exactly know where Jekyllnow's Gemfile is located. It's not in the root directory like it would otherwise be in a Github Pages repository.

If you are using JekyllNow directly from GitHub (i.e., you have forked the [JekyllNow repository](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now) to your GitHub account and are making changes there), then you do not have direct control over the `Gemfile`. In this mode of operation, GitHub Pages handles the Jekyll build process using a set of default and supported gems.

GitHub Pages has a set of dependencies that it uses for Jekyll, and Rouge is one of them. GitHub keeps these gems updated, but not always to the very latest version, due to stability and security considerations.

Since you cannot alter the gems or versions directly, your best immediate solution is to adjust the CSS as previously mentioned. That allows you to control the visual appearance even if you cannot change the way the lexer itself works.

A more involved solution would be, instead of letting GitHub Pages build your site, to set up a local Jekyll environment or use another CI/CD platform to build your site and then deploy the static files to GitHub Pages. That would give you control over the `Gemfile` and thus which versions of each gem, including Rouge, are used. But, given that you have opted for JekyllNow for simplicity, this might not be your preferred route.

Comment: I did some experimenting with the existing `_sass\highlights.scss` - that seems to be the file which is used for the highlighting. And the highlighting seems to work fine for `ruby` but not for `python`.

Comment: For python, practically every word in the code seems to be hightlighted by the entry `.highlight .nx { color: #555 } /* Name.Other` in the highlights.scss file. I am wondering if this is a bug!

Comment: If I instead mark the python code as ruby the highlighting seems better

Comment: Thank you. I use Jekyllnow - i.e. I don't install ruby or build locally. I am not sure where or how I check the Gemfile - don't exactly know where Jekyllnow's Gemfile is located. It's not in the root directory like it would otherwise be in a Github Pages repository. https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now

Comment: @user93353 Right, I missed the Jekyllnow part. I have edited the answer to address your latest comment.